# Why creating StaticArray with size from a variable throws an error?

Tags: arrays, crystal-lang

[error when creating StaticArray with size from variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JviTA.png)

I get this error (see image) but I don't know how to resolve this ?

code :

```
t = 3
seps = StaticArray(Int32, t).new{
      2
}
seps.each{|i| p i}
```

error :

```
Syntax error in eval:2: expecting token ')', not 't'
```

It works when I initialize the StaticArray like this :

```
seps = StaticArray(Int32, 3).new{
      2
}
seps.each{|i| p i}
```

But I need to init the array like the first sample of code !

Comment: Put your code here and not in an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [StaticArray](https://crystal-lang.org/api/StaticArray.html) has a fixed size that can't be modified at runtime. The syntax doesn't even allow to use a variable as a generic argument because it wouldn't make sense.

If you need variable size at runtime, you should use Array instead.